# Как правильно файлы поместить в List<byte[]>?

Tags: c#

Получаю список нужных файлов по расширению

```
FileInfo[] fln = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\TEST").GetFiles();
foreach(var fl in fln) {
    if (fl.Extension == ".d3a1") {
        byte[] flds = File.ReadAllBytes(fl.FullName);
        lisf.Add(flds);
    }
}
```

Но в лист заноситься как System.Byte[] - подскажите как правильно добавить с дальнейшим восстановлением.

P.S делаю загрузку аддонов через ulink - нужно передать клиенту по готовой сети

Comment: "Но в лист заноситься как System.Byte[]" - как Вы это выяснили? `.ToString()`?

Comment: @Igor вывел в консоль + textbox без .ToString()

Comment: `.ToString()` вызывается внутри `Console.Write`. Массивы байт у Вас грузятся правильно. Что Вы там (в консоли), собственно, хотели увидеть?

Comment: @Igor хотел увидеть эти байты

Comment: Та-а-ак, очень хорошо. Как, по-Вашему, выглядит типичный байт?

Comment: @Igor числа например 208
178
208
176
208
191
208
176
208
178
208
191
208

Comment: `Console.WriteLn(System.BitConverter.ToString(flds));`

Comment: @Igor а можно ли из string назад в байты?

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Writeline()` вызывает метод `ToString()` для каждого объекта. Вы отдали туда `byte[]`, в консоль вывелось то, что выводится по `ToString`.
Для вашей задачи вы можете использовать подобный код:

```
        // Массив байтов в строку
        yourString = Convert.ToBase64String(yourByteArray);
        // Строка в массив байтов
        yourByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(yourString);
```